# VBA Code to Clear Contents Based on Criteria

Tags: for-loop, if-statement

I am needing to automate the clearing of errors from pasted data from the output of an ERP program.  The pasted data range is from column A to column M, but column N is used to convert date entries of column K that are text-based (unusable by Conditional Formatting) to usable dates via the 'DATEVALUE" command.  This entire data set is over 3,000 lines long.

I've also added a command [IF(ISERROR...)] in column P to create an alternative method for identifying the errors.  This approach is unused by the code below, but it referenced in the section header.

IMPORTANT NOTE:  I need this code to be initiated automatically when the data is either pasted (hence the Sub Worksheet_Change) or when the user clicks other adjacent tabs (that report the data in separate groupings).

---

Here is the VBA code I have been trying to debug...

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim n As Variant
Dim i As Long

```
'ASSIGN THE NUMBER OF FILLED ROWS IN COLUMN 'A' TO VARIABLE "n"
    n = Range("B2").Value
    'MsgBox "n = " & n
    
                        
'FOR / NEXT loop to locate "TRUE" in column P and Clear Contents of the cell in column K of that row
     'i.e.:  CLEAR CONTENTS OF 'TXTEXT' CELLS THAT RESULT IN "#VALUE!" IN "CERT DATE" COLUMN
   
    For i = 202 To (202 + n - 3109) 'for rows 202 to 209
        'Cells("K", i).Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Cells("K", i).ClearContents)  (UNUSED LINE)
        'If Sheet1.Range("N" & i) <> "Open" Then                                       (UNUSED LINE)
            Range("K" & i).ClearContents
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError("N" & i) Then Range("K" & i).ClearContents
        
        MsgBox "i = " & i
        End If
        MsgBox "The last i = " & i
    Next i
```

End Sub

Thanks to all who review this.

Stephen

I should have explained that Column K contains mostly good dates, but some blank cells contain an error from the ERP software.

I was expecting the code to grab the max quantity of rows (already present in cell B2) and use that in a For/Next loop to test the entries of column K for errors.  If an error is identified in column K, then the code, via If...IsError, would clear the contents of the cell in column K of the same row.  Removing the errors in column K will improve the functionality of the grouping tabs that pull data directly from this 'Data Tab'.

Comment: I need to clarify the numbers of the 'For' line:  This was a test for the "IsError" command (rows 207 & 208 contain the errors in question) as well as the accuracy of the "n" value.